# Url Detection in Magento where Varnish is Active

Tags: php, magento, varnish

I'm using Magento in conjunction with Varnish Cache and I'm developing a module.

Here's my plan: detect URL at the `controller_action_predispatch` event and if the URL matches what I'm looking for, run a method.

Pretty simple, and this works:

```
$this->_action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
$request = $this->_action->getRequest();
if ($request->getRequestString() == 'my route') {
    //Process Action
}
```

Say for example, I look for `/checkout/cart/` as an example, then this works fine... locally.

On our staging server, we have Varnish Cache running via the Nexcess Turpentine extension. So, `/checkout/cart/` looks like this instead:

```
/turpentine/esi/getBlock/method/esi/access/private/ttl/86400/hmac/7b123a94c32437dbc3e871e9a8671e0c25acfd8b0d9aac4ef67e1a1e0ffe75b0/data/FG4tbo.vXe1BP-stDckM6MmxY8YJuimtBsPXs4DN60EvEjeTv6qGAV8dLiEF6AySMcp8zBoGCxrPo-3i6h1IeueERsjAyw8sRQcvh-5nmMr8wqUlNR36YRv6tgHn9tDsRBwjm6AurTfx46dLgi6HFhJcUwpPkl957MQhMBsN5tfwLWnYS7U0SfNxYKvHaXXyHQcvGVNEpfUKUMPsICC7wzJ7iGaahd8akvZ1VpZ.ifLOfWaXDlqdybZaQj2ZPq85DzBrM2-6sVbdv1fL4OOZxC-0A5iizQcwg9leLR1.n67bKCHYpndbfVxUpTN1Dxystq463pzP5tlm-sy6Sg6GH743ZQw6BMG8wlbgnPfWDu5Gf1Ty1K3Ercz54eOB59r7OCIUzEYE9HFQreMzIUaTEMg9GHBakggdyyi4WuHSB6E=/
```

I've also tried checking the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` which yields the same result and `Mage::helper('core/helper')->getCurrentUrl();` which is the same again.

I need to find out what route the Varnish Output resolves to, otherwise I cannot judge what page the user is currently visiting.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is very old question, but maybe someone is still struggling with this issue. To fix it I had to add registry_keys param in turpentine_esi.xml file:

```
<action method="setEsiOptions">
    <params>
        <access>private</access>
        <scope>page</scope>
        <ttl>0</ttl>
        <registry_keys>
            <current_category/>
        </registry_keys>
     </params>
  </action>
```